# Is arriving at FRA by train 3 hours before my flight early enough?

Tags: airport-transfer, frankfurt, deutsche-bahn

I am arriving Frankfurt(M)Flughafen by a DB bahn train from Hannover, which reaches at 11:17. My flight is from the Frankfurt airport terminal 2 at 14:15. Do I have sufficient time to reach the boarding gate, after carrying out the baggage check-in process and all security checks?.

I need to account for the possible delays of the DB bahn, walking time from the railway station to terminal 1, shuttle service at terminal 1, and so on. Have I allowed enough time?

Comment: Do you need to change trains on your way from Hannover to Frankfurt or in Hannover? If yes, how much later will the next train arrive if you miss your connection?

Comment: Yes, I start from Magdeburg and reach Hannover at 08:23. My connecting train starts at 08:41 and the next train, given I miss the connection, starts at 09:03 and reaches Frankfurt(M)Flughafen at 11:51. If I miss this as well, the next starts at 09:41 and reaches 12:22.

Comment: My instinct says that this should be absolutely fine - you rarely need to leave more than around 3 hours including buffer time for delays. But I've never used the airport myself so I won't answer.

Comment: @jsid Given the alternative connections I think you should be fine, but I only once used terminal 2 and there were no waiting times at all, but this was more than 10 years ago and things might have changed so I'm a bit hesitant to put this down as an answer. Does your airline provide the AiRail Check-in service (https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/de/reisevorbereitung/check-in/airail-check-in.html)? If yes, that could save you some valuable minutes if you're running late...

Comment: @Sabine Thanks for the link, I see that AiRail check-in is available at Hall D for UAI.

Comment: Correction. I see that AiRail check-in is not available of UAI, however, normal check-in counters are available at Hall D.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming your train is on time, or not extremely late, then you will have plenty of time.

The Fernbahnhof (long distance train station) at Frankfurt airport is connected via a covered walkway to Terminal 1, which takes about 10 minutes to walk.
(Please note that there are 2 train stations at the airport.  You will arrive at the Fernbahnhof, the other regional train station is for local trains)

Allow yourself another 3 - 5 to walk to the Skyline from where you take the Skyline train to terminal 2.  Which takes approx. another 5 mins.
Then allow yourself 5 mins to get to the check-in desks.
So altogether 20 minutes is normally enough.
(I assume you have good mobility)

Terminal 2 is smaller than T1 so it does not take so long to pass through the various stages.  Although you can still have a long walk!

Please note:  If you follow the signs from the Fernbahnhof to Terminal 2 it will send you to take a bus transfer.  This can take much longer, as the busses only drive every 10 minutes and often get stuck in traffic, which is worse due to the roadworks.  Last October it took me 40 minutes!
So I suggest instead heading into Terminal 1 and then follow signs to Skyline & Terminal 2.

Comment: Oh!...I was planning to take the bus, since I thought it will be faster. But since you have experienced otherwise, I suppose taking the skyline is faster.

Comment: If you are lucky with timing then Bus can be OK, but it is more hit & miss.  Skyline is more reliable and frequent.   Bus is probably better if you have a lot or very heavy luggage as it is less walking and taking luggage up/down escalators etc.

Comment: Many airlines also allow [checking in and dropping off your luggage directly at the long distance railway station](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/check-in/airail-check-in.html). This is extremely convenient as usually the queues are short here and it allows you to move to the terminal without the burden of your checked luggage.